# Showing that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{k} \cos(kx) = \frac{1- a \cos x}{1-2a \cos x + a^{2}}$ without using complex variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

The identity $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{k} \cos(kx) = \frac{1- a \cos x}{1-2a \cos x + a^{2}} \ ,  \ |a| <1$$

can be derived by using the fact that $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a^{k} \cos(kx) = \text{Re} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (ae^{ix})^{k}$.

But can it be derived without using complex variables?

Comment: What do you want to show exactly the sum identity or the integral?

Comment: This can also be seen as a mild restatement of the generating function for Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal The sum identity. That's just a link to the other thread.

Comment: You can use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567771/to-find-z-transform-of-given-sequence).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: doesn't that method use complex variables?

Comment: @RandomVariable I was happy to see my response below sufficiently satisfied Pranav for him to award his bounty (though he may have done so somewhat by default since I was the only user to attempt a response after he posted the bounty). But since this was originally you're question, I would also be interested in feedback from you. Is there any way in which you find it unsatisfying or think it might be improved? The reason I take such an interest here is (as you likely noticed) this is a key lemma in solving many integrals by purely real methods, and I anticipate citing it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidH  If I were asked to prove the multiple angle formula for cosine, I would use Euler's formula. But I guess you could prove it by induction without using Euler's formula.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/16/05/02/0003/),

$$\cos{\left(nx\right)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\cos^{n-2k}{\left(x\right)},$$

the infinite series in question may be rewritten as a double infinite series over a triangle. Changing the order of summation (if you're like me and the transformation gymnastics with multiple indices makes you dizzy, here's a very handy [cheat-sheet](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/)), we're left with fairly elementary summations:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{n}\cos{\left(nx\right)}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\cos^{n-2k}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}a^{n}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\cos^{n-2k}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\binom{2k+n}{2k}a^{2k+n}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\cos^{n}{\left(x\right)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ka^{2k}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2k+n}{2k}\left[a\cos{\left(x\right)}\right]^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ka^{2k}\sin^{2k}{\left(x\right)}\frac{1}{\left(1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}\right)^{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\left[\frac{a\sin{\left(x\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right]^{2k}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\left[\frac{a\sin{\left(x\right)}}{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}\right]^{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}\cdot\frac{\left(1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}\right)^2}{\left(1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}\right)^2+a^2\sin^2{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1-2a\cos{\left(x\right)}+a^2\cos^2{\left(x\right)}+a^2\sin^2{\left(x\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1-a\cos{\left(x\right)}}{1-2a\cos{\left(x\right)}+a^2}.~~\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 16):

Here is a very inelegant proof:
\begin{eqnarray}
(1-2a\cos x+a^2)&\times&\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k\cos(kx) \\&=&\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k\cos(kx)-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^k\cos((k-1)x)\cos x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty a^k\cos((k-2)x)\\
&=&1-a\cos x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty a^k\left[\cos(kx)-2\cos((k-1)x)\cos x+\cos(k-2)x) \right]\\
&=&1-a\cos x\, .
\end{eqnarray}

**Edit.** I just realize that this is LutzL's answer

Comment: There may be some... I agree with you that it would be much better!

Answer (score 7):

This has a standard approach: You multiply with the denominator of the right fraction, sort the product with the series on the left by powers of $a$ and apply trigonometric identities to the resulting coefficients of $a^n$. Everything should cancel except the lowest order terms that constitute the numerator of the right side.

---

One should also note that this is the Poisson kernel of the Abel summation method for Fourier series, see for instance [Carl Offner: "A little harmonic analysis"](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/) (Online PDF article)