# Show $\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(\frac{7+5 \cos x}{10+6\cos x}\right) \cos \left( \frac{\sin x}{10+6 \cos x} \right) dx = 2\pi e^{2/3}$ Real Methods

Tags: calculus, integration

Taken from the post: [The Integral that Stumped Feynman?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253910/the-integral-that-stumped-feynman)

I want to know if the integral:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \exp\left(\frac{7+5 \cos x}{10+6\cos x}\right) \cos \left( \frac{\sin x}{10+6 \cos x} \right) dx = 2\pi e^{2/3}$$

can be evaluated using strictly real methods.

I've tried series of $e^x$ and $\cos x$ but to no avail. I tried differentiating under the integral, but nothing seemed to come out of it. Is there any wizardry that can conjure up this answer without complex analysis.

Comment: Would Weierstrass substitution help?

Comment: Just gave it a try, didn't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there no way you could use complex analysis rather than strictly real?

Comment: Since exp(a+b)=exp(a)exp(b) then the equality is equivalent to something like: $\int$ exponential() cosinus()=$2\pi$

Comment: Of course $$\left(\frac{7+5 \cos x}{10+6\cos x}\right)+i \left( \frac{\sin x}{10+6 \cos x} \right)$$ describes a circle in the complex plane.  And our integrand is the real part of the exponential of it.  So (as known) we can do it by complex methods.

Comment: Does [this solution](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1705269p10979023) not count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start with $\tan \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)$$=2\tan \left( \frac{t}{2} \right)$ $$I=2\int_0^{\pi} \exp\left(\frac{7+5 \cos x}{10+6\cos x}\right) \cos \left( \frac{\sin x}{10+6 \cos x} \right) dx=8e^{5/8}\int_0^{\pi}\exp\left(\frac{\cos t}{8}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sin t}{8}\right)\frac{dt}{5-3\cos t} $$ Using $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n} \cos(nx) = \frac12\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{1-2 a \cos x + a^{2}}-1\right)$$ we can rewrite $$\frac{1}{5-3\cos x} =\frac14 +\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \cos (nx) $$ thus we have $$I=2e^{5/8} \int_0^\pi \exp\left(\frac{\cos t}{8}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sin t}{8}\right) dt +4e^{5/8} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} \int_0^\pi \exp\left(\frac{\cos t}{8}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sin t}{8}\right) \cos(nt )dt $$
$$=2\pi e^{5/8}+4e^{5/8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} I(n)$$ I dont know how to evaluate $I(n)$, but maybe someone can help.
$$I(0)=\pi,I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2^4}, I(2)=\frac{\pi}{2^8}, I(3)=\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 2^{11}}, I(4)=\frac{\pi}{3\cdot2^{16}},I(5)=\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 2^{19}}$$$$ I(6)=\frac{\pi}{3^2\cdot5\cdot 2^{23}}, I(10)=\frac{\pi}{3^4\cdot5^2\cdot 7 \cdot 2^{39}}, I(20)=\frac{\pi}{3^8\cdot5^4 \cdot 7^2\cdot11\cdot 13\cdot 17\cdot 19\cdot 2^{79}}$$

Edit:  As seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2913057/515527 $ I(n) =\frac{\pi} {2^{3n+1}n!}$, plugging this into the sum and using the series for $e^x$ will give the result immediately..

Another approach to evaluate $I(n)$ is to use that $$\exp\left(\frac{\cos t}{8}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sin t}{8}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nt)}{8^nn!}$$ Since $$\int_0^\pi \cos(nx) \cos(mx) dx=\begin{cases} \frac{\pi} {2} & n=m \\ 0 & n \neq m\end{cases}$$ We get that $I(n) =\frac{\pi} {2} \frac{1} {8^n n!} $ and the result follows.

Comment: We might conjecture that $I(n) = \pi/2^{4n}$

Comment: Well, this way we get $I=\frac{98}{47}\pi e^{5/8}$, Unfortunately $ \frac{98}{47}\pi e^{5/8}-2\pi e^{2/3}= 0.000073...$ :(

Comment: Yes, the patterns unfortunately breaks down.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure you can prove the series identity used by real methods.

Comment: look 
here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685278/showing-that-sum-k-0-infty-ak-coskx-frac1-a-cos-x1-2a-cos

Comment: @Zacky: Nice work! I have added another mild example ... https://math.stackexchange.com/a/431366