# Prove $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\text{cos}kx=\frac{1-a\text{cos}x}{1-2a\text{cos}x+a^2}, \; |a|<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series

I want to prove the following;

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}=\frac{1-a\cos{x}}{1-2a\cos{x}+a^2}, \; |a|<1 \tag{1}$$

I know that;

$$\text{S}(r)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}, \; |r|<1$$

We can use this expression by rewriting (1);

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}=\text{Re}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(a\text{e}^{\pm ix})^k\right]=\text{Re}\left[\text{S}(a\text{e}^{\pm ix})\right]$$

Evaluating this sum we get;

$$\text{Re}\left[\text{S}(a\text{e}^{\pm ix})\right]=\text{Re}\left[\frac{1}{1-[a \text{e}^{\pm ix}]}\right]=\text{Re}\left[\frac{1-a\text{e}^{\pm ix}}{\left(1-a\text{e}^{\pm ix}\right)^2}\right]=\text{Re}\left[\frac{1-a\text{e}^{\pm ix}}{1+(a\text{e}^{\pm ix})^2-2a\text{e}^{\pm ix}}\right] \tag{3}$$

Now this would, in fact, be eq. (1) if; $1+(a\text{e}^{\pm ix})^2-2a\text{e}^{\pm ix}=1-2a\cos{x}+a^2$, however, I cannot see how we get rid of the two terms containing $\text{e}^{\pm ix}$, after all one term depends on $a$ while the other depends on $a^2$. Do anyone have an idea/a trick to use to derive eq. (1) from my current work?

Comment: To find the rael part of $\frac 1 z$ you don't multiply numerator and denominator by $z$. You  multiply numerator and denominator by $\overline z$.

Comment: Helpful info here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/685278/

Comment: Thank you. I successfully derived eq. (1) by multiplying the numerator and denominator of $\frac{1}{z}$ by $\bar{z}$.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(ae^{ix}\right)^k=\frac{1}{1-ae^{ix}}\frac{1-ae^{-ix}}{1-ae^{-ix}}=\frac{1-ae^{-ix}}{1-a(e^{-ix}+e^{ix})+a^2}=\frac{1-ae^{-ix}}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eq. (3), instead of multiplying $\frac{1}{z}$ by $z$ in the numerator and denominator, we multiply by $\bar{z}$ in the numerator and denominator. This yields;

$$\text{Re}\left[\frac{1}{1-a\cos{x}-ai\sin{x}}\right]=\text{Re}\left[\frac{1-a\cos{x}+ai\sin{x}}{(1-a\cos{x})^2+(a\sin{x})^2}\right]=\text{Re}\left[\frac{1-a\cos{x}+ai\sin{x}}{1+a^2-2a\cos{x}}\right]=\frac{1-a\cos{x}}{1+a^2-2a\cos{x}}$$

$\textbf{Note}$; For a complex number, $z=a+ib$, we have $|z|^2=\left[\text{Re}(z)\right]^2+\left[\text{Im}(z)\right]^2$

Which proves that; $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}=\frac{1-a\cos{x}}{1-2a\cos{x}+a^2}$

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick of
introducing
$\cos(x)
=\Re(e^{ix})
$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(x, a)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\Re(e^{ikx})\\
&=\Re(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^ke^{ikx})\\
&=\Re(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(ae^{ix})^k)\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1}{1-ae^{ix}})\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1}{1-a\cos(x)-ai\sin(x)})\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1}{1-a\cos(x)-ai\sin(x)})\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)}{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)})\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)}{(1-a\cos(x))^2+a^2\sin^2(x)})\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)}{1+2a\cos(x)+a^2\cos^2(x)+a^2\sin^2(x)})\\
&=\Re(\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)}{1+2a\cos(x)+a^2})\\
&=\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)}{1+2a\cos(x)+a^2})\\
\\
\text{also}\\
s(x, a)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\sin{kx}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\Im(e^{ikx})\\
&=\Im(\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)+ai\sin(x)}{1+2a\cos(x)+a^2})\\
&=\dfrac{a\sin(x)}{1+2a\cos(x)+a^2})\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

An elementary proof
not using complex numbers.

$\begin{array}\\
d(x, a)
&=(1-2a\cos{x}+a^2)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}-2a\cos{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}+a^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}-2\cos{x}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{k+1}\cos{kx}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{k+2}\cos{kx}\\
&=1+a\cos(x)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}-2\cos{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-1)x}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-2)x}\\
&=1+a\cos(x)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}-2\cos{x}(a+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-1)x})+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-2)x}\\
&=1+a\cos(x)-2a\cos(x)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^k\cos{kx}-2\cos{x}(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-1)x})+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^{k}\cos{(k-2)x}\\
&=1-a\cos(x)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}a^k(cos(kx)-2\cos(x)\cos((k-1)x)+\cos((k-2)x)\\
&=1-a\cos(x)
\qquad\text{(since }\cos(kx)=2\cos(x)\cos((k-1)x)-\cos((k-2)x))\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

A more general case,
with an obvious relation to
the power series for
a linear recurrence relation.

If $\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x)
=0$
then
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^kf_k(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a^k(\sum_{j=0}^k g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x))}{\sum_{j=0}^m a^jg_j(x)}
$.

Standard examples
with $f_k(x)=f(kx)$:

$(f(x), m, recurrence, g_j(x), result)\\
(\cos(x). 2, 0=\cos(kx)-2\cos(x)\cos((k-1)x)+\cos((k-2)x), (1, -2\cos(x), 1),\dfrac{1-a\cos(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2})\\
(\sin(x). 2, 0=\sin(kx)-2\cos(x)\sin((k-1)x)+\sin((k-2)x),  (1, -2\cos(x), 1), \dfrac{a\sin(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2})
$

The derivation.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=0}^m a^jg_j(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^kf_k(x)
&=\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^{k+j}f_k(x)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)\sum_{k=j}^{\infty}a^{k}f_{k-j}(x)\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)(\sum_{k=j}^{m}a^{k}f_{k-j}(x)+\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}a^{k}f_{k-j}(x))\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)\sum_{k=j}^{m}a^{k}f_{k-j}(x)+\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}a^{k}f_{k-j}(x)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\sum_{j=0}^k g_j(x)a^{k}f_{k-j}(x)+\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}a^{k}\sum_{j=0}^m g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{m}a^{k}\sum_{j=0}^k g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a^kf_k(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=0}^{m}a^{k}\sum_{j=0}^k g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x)}{\sum_{j=0}^m a^jg_j(x)}
$.

Coefficients of $a^k$:

$\begin{array}\\
k
&\sum_{j=0}^k g_j(x)f_{k-j}(x)\\
0
&g_0(x)f_0(x)\\
1
&g_0(x)f_1(x)+g_1(x)f_0(x)\\
2
&g_0(x)f_2(x)+g_1(x)f_1(x)+g_2(x)f_0(x)\\
\end{array}
$